# Is it possible to embed a custom report to a run page?

Tags: github-actions

I'm running some Cypress tests, and I'm using `cypress-mochawesome-reporter` to generate reports. But now I'm struggling to find a way to put those reports in the GitHub Action's page where you can see details of a run.

Is that even possible? I saw `dotnet-tests-report` doing something similar, but I can't find anything on how to do it....

Comment: If you have access to the report itself, you can redirect it to `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` and it'll show up as a [job summary](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary).